# SQL query to select apps used at least once during 3 different days in the last 7 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains 2 columns : 1 column "app_id" and 1 column "time".
I am trying to make a SQL request to know the number of "app_id" that have been used at least once in 3 different days, in the last 7 days.

Currently, I achieved selecting all the data in the last 7 days using :

```
SELECT app_id,time FROM connexions WHERE time BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 167 HOUR AND NOW()
```

*I am using 167 HOUR instead of 7 DAY because I have a 1 hour time difference between my server and the database (no worries about that, i'll fix it later!)*

Thanks!

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: [Edit] your question and provide the `CREATE TABLE` statement for `connexions` and sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements. Also show the desired result with that sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  SELECT app_id
  FROM connexions 
  WHERE time BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 167 HOUR AND NOW()
  GROUP BY app_id
  HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT day(time) )  > 3
```

Be aware this only works because is a week. If you want something like 3 months you would need be more specific.